# How would I create a new HTML element through code that everyone can see

Tags: html

I am quite new to HTML and JavaScript and I created this extremely basic website that is meant to be a messaging thing. In theory you type your message and press the send button, and it creates a new HTML element. But the new element is only shown to the window that it is sent on. Here is the [link](https://coolmessaging.000webhostapp.com/) for my deployed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for everyone to see the changes, you need to have a server where you'll be sending the text after clicking send, and on the server, you'll be broadcasting the received text to all the windows that are open currently.

Check out [socket.io](https://socket.io/) it is beginner-friendly to learn this kind of stuff.